Scale from A4 to A5 for documentclass book

Original question:
I found the answer from Simon Dispa with the following proposal:
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\mag=1414 % added <<<<<

\PassOptionsToPackage{usegeometry, paper=a5, pagesize, BCOR = 12mm, DIV = 16}{typearea}
\documentclass[fontsize=9pt, twoside=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}  

\usepackage{layout}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\lay@value}[2]{\strip@pt\dimexpr0.351459\dimexpr\csname#2\endcsname\relax\relax mm}
\makeatother

\usepackage[cross, a4,center,noinfo,horigin=-1in, vorigin=-1in]{crop} % <<<<<<<<< added

%   \usepackage{geometry}
%   \geometry{paper=a4paper, layout=a4paper,  layouthoffset=7.0135mm, layoutvoffset=9.4651mm}            % Case 1 

%\AtEndPreamble{\usepackage{hyperref}}  

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\layout
\blindmathpaper

\end{document}

This code scales the document (scrbook) from A5 to A4.
Now I am looking for the right settings for my document, where I use \documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper]{book} and \geometry{a4paper, includeheadfoot, top=1.8cm, bottom=1.8cm, right=2.5cm, left=2.5cm}, in order to scale exactly the other way round, i.e. from A4 to A5.
This is my first question here in the forum. I am also a newbie with Latex. So I hope I have asked the question in the right way.
I would be glad if you could help me out.
Thank you very much in advance.

Extended question:
If I combine the answer from Simon Dispa with @cfr suggestion and adjust it accordingly so that the scaling is from A4 to A5, I already get a pretty good solution:
\mag=707 % cfr's suggestion

\PassOptionsToPackage{usegeometry, paper=a4, pagesize, BCOR = 12mm, DIV = 16}{typearea}

\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{layout}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\lay@value}[2]{\strip@pt\dimexpr0.351459\dimexpr\csname#2\endcsname\relax\relax mm}
\makeatother

\usepackage[cross, a5,center,noinfo,horigin=-1in, vorigin=-1in]{crop} 


\usepackage{blindtext}  
\usepackage[includeheadfoot, top=1.8cm, bottom=1.8cm, right=2.5cm, left=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\blindmathpaper

\end{document} 

However, I don't know whether there is a need to adjust the following parameters or lines of code:

BCOR = 12mm and DIV = 16 in \PassOptionsToPackage{usegeometry, paper=a4, pagesize, BCOR = 12mm, DIV = 16}{typearea}
\renewcommand*{\lay@value}[2]{\strip@pt\dimexpr0.351459\dimexpr\csname#2\endcsname\relax\relax mm}
horigin=-1in and vorigin=-1inin \usepackage[cross, a5,center,noinfo,horigin=-1in, vorigin=-1in]{crop}

I hope that can be answered.
Perhaps it is also possible to clarify why the parameters or lines of code are needed at all.

Welcome! It's not entirely clear to me what code you are trying to use. You say you're using book, but the code you've posted uses scrbook. Can you change the code so it reflects what you're trying to do? People can click through for the solution you linked if they want to. (I just did this, actually, trying to understand your question.)

Thank you very much for the hint. I have extended my original question accordingly, taking into account your suggestion below with \mag=707.

Are you actually using the typearea package? If not, passing it options does no harm, but it won't have any effect. I don't understand why you want crop here. I thought you were scaling from A4 design to A5 paper, so what is crop for?

As commented on your suggestion below, if I only use \mag=707, my A5 version will not look like yours. In my case, the text virtually runs over the right-hand edge of the page and so part of the text disappears. I have therefore combined your suggestion and the original answer from Simon Dispa. To be honest, I don't know why the typearea package and why crop is used here. That's exactly what I'm wondering, which is why I extended the original question. I am also unsure whether I need to change the parameters here.

As far as I have now understood, I really don't need the typearea package here. It only seems to be necessary for KOMA-Script documents. Many thanks to @crf for the hint. However, it looks like I have to add the line \usepackage[cross, a5,centre,noinfo,horigin=-1in, vorigin=-1in]{crop}  so that the text is placed exactly on the A5 page. Otherwise the text will continue to run over the edge. However, I still cannot explain why I need horigin=-1in and vorigin=-1in. Perhaps someone can shed some light on this?

All I can say is, that I can't reproduce that based on the code you've provided. The -1in is probably (but this is just a guess) to offset the default 1in margin TeX always uses. Don't use both typearea and geometry because they'll just conflict.

Many thanks again for your helpful comments.

I am not sure I've well understood your question, but maybe this will help. As far as I understand it, the code you've posted doesn't actually reflect what you're trying to do. Instead, you have something like this:
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}  
\usepackage[includeheadfoot, top=1.8cm, bottom=1.8cm, right=2.5cm, left=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\blindmathpaper

\end{document}

which produces something like the following when compiled (pdfTeX):


and you want it to look like this on A5:


which can be produced using
\mag=707

\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}  
\usepackage[includeheadfoot, top=1.8cm, bottom=1.8cm, right=2.5cm, left=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\blindmathpaper

\end{document}

Since 707 is the inversion of 1414.
Note that typographic quality will be compromised when scaling the document like this. Scaling the standard 12pt font is not equivalent to using the font in the appropriate smaller size if the font provides optical sizes, which the default TeX fonts do. That is, an x at 5pt isn't a shrunken x at 8pt, say, but a slightly different character designed to enhance legibility at small sizes.
But to satisfy some bureaucratic requirement, for example, the code should do the job.

Thank you very much!
If I implement your suggestion, my A5 version will not look like yours. In my case, the text virtually runs over the right-hand edge of the page and so part of the text disappears. I have therefore extended my original question to take your suggestion into account.

Could you please explain in more detail what you mean by Note that typographic quality will be compromised when scaling the document like this. Scaling the standard 12pt font is not equivalent to using the font in the appropriate smaller size if the font provides optical sizes, which the default TeX fonts do. That is, an x at 5pt isn't a shrunken x at 8pt, say, but a slightly different character designed to enhance legibility at small sizes.
What are optical sizes?

@ThomasJ If I compile the updated code from your question, I get similar output to that shown above, with the addition of crop marks in odd places. The text doesn't touch the edges of the paper and certainly doesn't disappear. To remove the crop marks, delete the line loading crop. I don't know what's causing your text to disappear because you've not shown the code responsible for that. But you don't need the typearea, crop or layout lines. (layout is OK to test the layout, but don't load it in your final version; you aren't using typearea here; crop doesn't apply.)

Better quality fonts are provided in multiple sizes. Computer Modern Roman and Latin Modern Roman both come in several sizes, for example. Typically, characters at smaller sizes use proportionally thicker strokes and perhaps simpler shapes to enhance legibility. So a 5pt a is not the same as a scaled-down 10pt a and won't generally be as easy to read or look quite as good. With older fonts, things were worse because TeX originally used non-vector fonts which also got fuzzy if enlarged. That probably doesn't apply, but you'll still get a less optimal optical size.

Thank you very much for your comments on the typographic quality. That makes it clear to me.
